# skipping the complete row if len() of column is lower than 10 in python

Tags: python, django, postgresql, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to apply an if statement in my django view script that would skip the complete row of the product if the description lenght is less than 10, but I don't know how to achieve this..

This is my Django view that calls an API and save the data into my database and as you will see in the commented section this is what I came out with so far:

```
def api_data(request):
    if request.GET.get('mybtn'):  # to improve, == 'something':
        resp_1 = requests.get(
            "https://www.headout.com/api/public/v1/product/listing/list-by/city?language=fr&cityCode=PARIS&limit=5000&currencyCode=CAD",
            headers={
                "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
            })
        resp_1_data = resp_1.json()
        base_url_2 = "https://www.headout.com/api/public/v1/product/get/"

        translator = Translator()

        for item in resp_1_data['items']:
            print('parsing, translating and saving item {}'.format(item['id']))
            # concat ID to the URL string
            url = '{}{}'.format(base_url_2, item['id'] + '?language=fr')

            # make the HTTP request
            resp_2 = requests.get(
                url,
                headers={
                    "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
                })
            resp_2_data = resp_2.json()


            descriptiontxt = resp_2_data['contentListHtml'][0]['html'][0:2040] + ' ...'

            soup = BeautifulSoup(descriptiontxt, 'lxml')
            parsed = soup.find('p').text


            #what I tried so far

            #if len(parsed) < 10:
            #   skip the complete row and go to the next one


            translation = translator.translate(parsed, dest='fr')

            titlename = item['name']
            titlefr = translator.translate(titlename, dest='fr')

            destinationname = item['city']['name']
            destinationfr = translator.translate(destinationname, dest='fr')

            Product.objects.get_or_create(
                title=titlefr.text,
                destination=destinationfr.text,
                description=translation.text,
                link=item['canonicalUrl'],
                image=item['image']['url']
            )

            time.sleep(2)

    return render(request, "form.html")
```

Please help.

Comment: What is currently being returned in parsed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The product description is being returned in parsed.

Comment: so is your problem that the length is returned wrong? or is it returning the correct length but you just need to skip the loop of the length is less than 10?

Comment: It's returning the correct lenght, but I would like to skip the loop if the description lenght is less than 10. Because most of the time, if one of the product have a very short description lenght, there's no images attach to it and I want to make sure that every product are complete.

Comment: I also get a `List index out of range error` if the description has a lenght of 0, that's why I want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) if your length is less than 10 like so,

```
if len(parsed) < 10:
    continue
```

This will skip you current iteration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just tried and I still get the list index out of range error with the traceback pointing towards this line: descriptiontxt = resp_2_data['contentListHtml'][0]['html'][0:2040] + ' ...'

Comment: You need to check if your contentListHtml has any values before asking for index 0.

Comment: Cna I remove the [0] in the line?

Comment: What about this:              `try:
                descriptiontxt = resp_2_data['contentListHtml'][0]['html'][0:2040] + ' ...'
            except IndexError:
                continue`